# Installing Jenkins.war in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I want to install jenkins.war in Ubuntu.I have downloaded jenkins.war and it is place under home directory.What command do i need to write in the terminal to install jenkins.Please help

Comment: you need to install a web server, like tomcat. And deploy your war in it.

Comment: can you provide me any link which i can refer to install jenkins

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

Comment: @vincent I have just downloaded jenkins.war.I need to know what will be the path to jenkins home in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to install Jenkins on Ubuntu is to add Jenkins repository. 
Please follow the steps described in official [Jenkins web page.](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/) 
With proposed solution, you will not need to install and setup any additional applications (except java).

Comment: I am asking to jenkins.war installation not for standalone application

Comment: The "package" installation will: 1. install `jenkins.war` to `/usr/share/jenkins` directory. 2. install jenkins documentation. 3 create `/var/lib/jenkins` as a `jenkins user` home directory. 4. install to script `/etc/default/jenkins` with default runtime parameters. 5 install `/etc/init.d/jenkins` script that will allow you to demonize jenkins.

Comment: You still have your jenkins.war. Also you have a scripts that can use as a great reference how to run jenkins manually.

I'm really not a fan using jenkins with tomcat, especially if you do not know how to configure tomcat. For the first time I tried, I spent a lot of time reading `how to step by step` setup jenkins with tomcat.

Comment: I am getting the following error gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: Check to following discussion :http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196704 maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to install and run a WAR file. In ubuntu the fastest way would be to install Tomcat 7 like this.

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

You will also have to have Java installed. Once you have both Java and Tomcat installed you should add a couple lines to your .bashrc file like this.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export CATALINA_HOME=/path/to/tomcat
```

Then start Tomcat like this.

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

The try this URL and you should see the Apache Tomcat index page.

```
 your_IP_address:8080
```

Now, to deploy your WAR file in Tomcat you just need to copy the WAR file into the Webapps directory and restart Tomcat

Comment: when i try to start tomcat through $CATALINA_HOME it gives me following error  bash: /bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: I have been writing the command from the home directory.please do specify from which directory do i need to write the command

Comment: First remove the tilde from the CATALINA_HOME path. APT installs Tomcat in /usr/share/tomcat7. So your CATALINA_HOME should look like this export $CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7 with no spaces. Then you will be able to find /bin/startup.sh. If you have all your paths set correctly you can be in any directory and issue commands by referencing $CATALINA_HOME.

Comment: BTW, You may have more success with Jenkins by following the Jenkins install tutorial from @kkamilpl

Comment: actually i worked on windows using the jenkins.war which enabled me to invoke selenium scripts through jenkins.Thats why i wanted to work explicity on jenkins.war.

Comment: I have tried @kkamilpi method and I have installed jenkins but i am still not sure where it will server my purpose